# Insert into a table using values from another

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to perform an insert using the following command:

```
insert into table2(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) values((select COL1 FROM table1 WHERE COL1 = 121212),120,10,"Y");
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Any help?

Answer (score 5):

```
INSERT INTO table2( col1, col2, col3, col4 )
  SELECT col1, 120, 10, 'Y'
    FROM table1
   WHERE col1 = 121212
```

should work.

Comment: TO add to this, the reason OP's code doesn't work is because `select` does not return single results, but a set of results, so you cannot use a `select` as a single value. However, you can insert a set of data into your table, and the syntax for that is in Justin's answer.